# Extjs4.1 - Get Selected in treepanel fails

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a treepanel and i try to get node when i selected like **http://jsfiddle.net/kTedM/**

```
 Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        title: 'Simple Tree',
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        store: store,
        rootVisible: false,
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: {
                text: 'Get Selected nodes',
                handler: function(){
                    var s = this.up('panel').getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                    if (s[0])
                        alert(s[0].data.text + ' was selected');
                    else alert('no selected');
                }
            }
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

But If u follow below step u will see bug.

step1: run code and click `get selected nodes` u will get correct alert is `no selected`

step2: Double click in `homework` node and click `get selected nodes` u will see

[image]

But i see that node's not selected? How to fix that thanks

Comment: +1 for the  good complete running stand-alone code and the accurate description of the steps needed to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the 'homework' node **is** and **should be** selected. There's no reason that double-clicking it should deselect it.

The bug is that the fact that this node is selected is not correctly represented visually. Clearly a bug.

It has been fixed by Sencha in Ext4.2. See [this update of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kTedM/1/); I've just changed the version to 4.2.0 and there's nothing surprising going on...

So, to answer your very question, I'd say that in order to fix it, you just have to upgrade to the last version. I advice against the very last 4.2.1 that introduces several new bugs, but rather for the 4.2.0.x.

Now, here's some code, because I am forced by SO to post some in order to be allowed to link to the fiddle:

```
// Same code as you
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        fields: [
                {name: 'id',     type: 'string'},
                {name: 'text',     type: 'string'},
                {name: 'selected', type: 'string'}
        ],
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            id: '0',
            children: [{
                text: "detention",
                id: '1',
                leaf: true
            }, {
                text: "homework",
                id: '2',
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    id: '3',
                    text: "book report",
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    id: '4',
                    text: "alegrbra",
                    leaf: true,
                    selected: 'true'
                }]
            }, {
                id: '5',
                text: "buy lottery tickets",
                leaf: true
            }]
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        title: 'Simple Tree',
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        store: store,
        rootVisible: false,
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: {
                text: 'Get Selected nodes',
                handler: function(){
                    var s = this.up('panel').getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                    if (s[0])
                        alert(s[0].data.text + ' was selected');
                    else alert('no selected');
                }
            }
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```